# How to get the status of microphone in ReplayKit Broadcast Extension

Tags: ios, swift, screen-recording, replaykit

I am using ReplayKit Broadcast Extension to record system screen. I am able to get the sample buffer's for video, audioApp, audioMic & process them.

Is there any way to get the microphone status i.e whether it's enabled or disabled during the screen recording?

Answer (score 1):

If you have declared recorder as -

```
var recorder = RPScreenRecorder.shared()
```

Then you can check it as -

```
if recorder.isMicrophoneEnabled == true {

}
```

Comment: I tried this but getting **false** even if the mic is on. This can be because I am using **RPBroadcastExtension** for recording system screen(my app & other apps screens) not **RPScreenRecorder** as it only allows to record in app screen.